# Safe PDO mySQL SELECT statement with for loop

Tags: php, mysql, security, for-loop, pdo

I was told to use PDO to safely retrieve data from a database. Now I'm wondering if this would be safe or work at all:

```
$dbtype     = "sqlite";
$dbhost     = "localhost";
$dbname     = "test";
$dbuser     = "root";
$dbpass     = "admin";
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname",$dbuser,$dbpass);

$firstName = htmlspecialchars($_POST["firstName"]);
foreach($conn->query('SELECT * FROM employeeTable WHERE firstName = ' . $firstName) as $row) {
    echo $row['lastName'].' '.$row['email'];
}
```

Because to me it looks like it would still be possible to "inject" something into the query.

So my question is: Is that really safe and if not how exactly would I make it safe?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'd better use the following to prepare, the process of preparing is to void the injection

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM employeeTable WHERE firstName = :firstName';
$sth = $conn->prepare($sql); 
$sth -> bindParam(':firstName', $firstName);
$sth -> execute();
$result = $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->lastName, $value->email;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just remember to don't directly concatenate post variables to your query, just use prepared statements. And after the execution of prepared statements, you need to fetch the results:

```
$select = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM employeeTable WHERE firstName = :firstName');
$select->execute(array(':firstName' => $_POST["firstName"));

while($row = $select->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
    echo $row['lastName'].' '.$row['email'];
}
```

Here is a good read:

http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers